# How to send each time a file path to a class from sub-folders in JAVA

Tags: java, file, path, directory

hello i want to send to a class some paths of files.

I have a main folder called **FoderMain** which contains some
   sub-folders (*all different names*)

[image]

Each of them contains files like this:

[image]

I want to send to a class for each sub-folder its contents(paths of files)

[image]

...and then for the next sub fodler ( *until all sended* )

Until now I'm reading the total number of the subfolders using this code:

```
   public static int GetDBNumber()     {                                                       
     File file = new File("C:\\FoderMain");
     File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
     public boolean accept(File f) {
     return f.isDirectory();}});
     return files.length;      }          //in this example it will returns 5 sub-folders
```

then I'm trying to see the total files that i will send *(I'm thinking to do it with a while but I'm not sure if its needed)*

```
     public static int totalSubFiles()                                            { 
     File file = new File("C:\\FoderMain\\"+f.getName());
     File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter(){
     public boolean accept(File f) {
     return f.isDirectory();}});
     return files.length; 
   }
```

So far i can do this if i know already the name of the files and also there have to be only one in a sub folder with this way

```
     File file = new File("C:\\FolderMain");
          File[] files = file.listFiles(new FileFilter() {
          public boolean accept(File f) {
          Function_test t=new Function_test(f.getPath()+"\\"+name+".text");  //if i know the name aldready & there is only one file in the sub folder
          return f.isDirectory();}});
```

Any idea how it could work for unknown number and name?
*Hope that i explained as better i could*

Comment: You can use an ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can use java.nio.* package and some java 8 and you can write this

```
String Dir = "your directory path"; 
Files.walk(Paths.get(Dir)).forEach(System.out::println);
```

this will print all the files and folder names after that you can change a path to 
a file and filter however you like .